# unable to write tables using python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, scripting, xlsxwriter

I am working on a script to write multiple tables into a single Excel sheet. I am using python 2.6 and xlsxwriter to accomplish the task, but I am unable to create a table and no error shows up. Just the column names are added to the excel sheet. Here is the code I am using for creating the table

```
import xlsxwriter

report = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example_report.xlsx')
sheet = report.add_worksheet()

row_count = 0
column_count = 0

table_headers = [
    {'header': 'Product'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 1'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 2'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 3'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 4'},
]    

excel_write_data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000]

]

table_row_count = row_count+len(excel_write_data)
table_column_count = column_count+len(table_headers)

sheet.add_table(
    row_count, column_count,
    table_row_count, table_column_count,
    { 
        'data': excel_write_data,
        'columns': table_headers
    }
)

workbook.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not your complete code, so its pretty difficult to say where you are doing mistake! by the way, did you check any example on web before posting? you will find plenty of examples using xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as expected. Here is your code added to a complete program:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tables.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row_count = 0
column_count = 0

table_headers = [
    {'header': 'Product'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 1'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 2'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 3'},
    {'header': 'Quarter 4'},
    ]

excel_write_data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
]

table_row_count = row_count + len(excel_write_data)
table_column_count = column_count + len(table_headers)

worksheet.add_table(row_count, column_count,
                    table_row_count, table_column_count,
                    {'data': excel_write_data,
                     'columns': table_headers})

workbook.close()
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I would say that you should print out and debug the range that you are supplying to `add_table()`.

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara, But I was able generate the table only when I reduced the column count by 1, i.e; `table_column_count = column_count + len(table_headers)-1`. Can you let me know why that is happening? I am unable to have a empty column, with no name and data

Comment: You probably need to install the latest version of XlsxWriter (>= 0.94) to avoid a spurious warning about duplicate headers.